# php variable to know when jquery has loaded?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

I know you can get a $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] php variable if jquery has loaded. That's great but if you use an iframe then that variable is no longer available. Is there a way to detect if jquery has loaded and give php a varaible in an iframe? I don't want to load a header or footer if jquery has loaded 100% but otherwise put them on. I have to use an iframe so there is no way around that. (I'm using a Colorbox iframe).

Thank you.

Comment: PHP is server-side, jQuery is client-side. Are you trying to determine during the request for the iframe src whether jQuery has loaded in its parent?

Comment: "Are you trying to determine during the request for the iframe src whether jQuery has loaded in its parent?"

-Yes. Is there a php variable that either exists or that I can create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to hide the content with CSS using "display:none;" when Colorbox is enabled, You'd be still loading the footer and header but they won't show up

Comment: Excellent idea. Never thought of that. Thank you.

Comment: This solution may drastically affect the page. If the intent is to load the other page into the main page via AJAX, hiding header/footer won't prevent its scripts, CSS, etc. from being loaded into the loading page. Might wreak havoc in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

This approach seems error-prone. Do you have a good reason for waiting until jQuery has loaded before loading the header and footer? Are these actions that could be performed client-side via jQuery's AJAX functions?

Comment: I am using Colorbox iframe. I don't want the header or footer to show if two things:

1) Javascript is enabled
2) jquery has loaded

I say number 2 because a page can be heavy and still loading and if someone clicks on a link that is a colorbox then the new page will not be in a colorbox. It will just go to a new page. I do not want it to go to a new page without the header or footer. However, if Colorbox loaded correctly then I don't want a header or footer.

Comment: I agree, if I understand the OP's goals correctly, this seems like something that could be solved with an AJAX request ala $(window).load(function() { $.ajax(...); })

Answer (score 1):

> I know you can get a $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] php variable if jquery has loaded.

That's not what that variable indicates.

That variable indicates that a particular request was made with jQuery's AJAX functions.

Comment: +1 yup, it has nothing whatsoever to do with whether jQuery is active on the parent page or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

PHP  => Browser => Javascript

You can't communicate from javascript to php such that php would genereate different data based on javascript.

You can do a documentReady() to hide a div when jquery is loaded.